# Access parent class methods and variables

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following 3 classes in the same package:

```
class Machine {

    protected int id;

    public Machine(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Machine " + id + " starting.");
    }
}

class Car extends Machine {

    protected int id;

    public Car(int i) {
        super(i);
        id = i;
    }

    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.out.println("Car " + id + " starting.");
        System.out.println("I can access parent variable" + super.id);
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine machine = new Machine(2);
        Car car = new Car(3);

        car.start();
        machine.start();
        machine = car;
        machine.start();
    }
}
```

I have a few questions about this now. Please let me know if I stop making sense and I'll try and rephrase myself.

1. Can I access car.super methods and variables from the main class
   ? If so how ?
2. When I instantiate a Car object I also have to initialize the
   members of the machine class by calling it's constructor. Does this
   mean that when I create a new Car object the total memory
   being used is the size of a Car object + the size of a Machine
   object ?
3. When I have the same variable 'id' in both classes and access it
   using a Car object I get the Car 'id', but when I have it only in
   the Machine class and access it I get the  Machine 'id'. Does this
   mean that in essence that I'm overriding Machine 'id'. I was
   under the assumption that member variables cannot be overridden,
   only methods can.

Comment: You should read some tutorials to your tags: Inheritance, Polymorphism

Comment: I have, but they miss out on a few details.

Comment: 1. Yes. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html
additional info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 1):

1.protected data members are accessed buy aggregate classes only.
2.no idea.
3.This is a example of dynamic binding. This holds the opps feature where parent needs an explicit cast to point to a aggregate class.

Comment: What if the data members were public, will.the answer to 1 change ?

Answer (score 0):

2) The notion of super and subclasses do not exist when allocating memory for operations.  Java looks at the memory needed for the fields and the instance.  It will look at the instance of `Machine` and allocate memory for the int `id` and then look at the instance of `Car`, sees that memory has already been allocated in the parent, and simply assigns the value.

If your `Car` class had a field labeled `number` and `id` then memory would be allocated for two fields.

check out this guy: [Java memory usage in inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891022/java-memory-usage-in-inheritance)