# what is the exact subclass of superclass structure? why this code not work as my thought?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
interface Test{
    public void test1();
    public void test2();
}
```

```
class TestParent implements Test{
    public TestParent(){}

    @Override
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Override
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
        test1();
    }
}
```

```
class TestChild extends TestParent{
    public TestChild(){}

    @Override
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test3");
    }

    @Override
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test4");
        super.test2();
    }
}
```

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test ob = new TestChild();
        ob.test2();
    }
}
```

in above my example code,
I thought the printed answer would be "test4 test2 test1"
but the real was "test4 test2 test3"
how can I find a keyword like this kind of example?
and how can I print "test4 test2 test1" with no changes to TestChild class.
I'm really confused.

Comment: You're calling `test1()`, which is a virtual method - so it's going to use the override from `TestChild`. It's hard to say anything more than that without knowing *why* you expected it to print `test1` rather than `test3`.

Comment: @Override
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
        test1();
    }

that test1(); is in the TestParent,  and I thought is pointing the TestParent.test1()

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Instead, edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: `super.test2()` is really calling the method declared in `TestParent`, but inside that method the actual instance (`this`)  is still the *original* instance, so calling `test1()`, even inside `TestParent`, will call the overridden method of its instance, that is, `TestChild.test1()`

Comment: @user16320675 thanks, then... there are no way to call TestParent.test1() from TestParent.test2() without changing main and TestChild?

Comment: @user16320675 how can I deeply find memory structure of inheritance like I asked ? I really can't find the keyword ..

Comment: not sure what you mean by "memory structure of inheritance"? And for sure I cannot find anything about memory in your question ("like I asked") ?? Do you mean something like the question [Java memory usage in inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25891022/16320675)?  But memory structure has nothing to do related to the question - memory structure is about how/where the fields are stored, not about which methods are called

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the functionality of test1 method in the parent class to a separate method and call it from test2, instead of a direct call to test1:

```java
class TestParent implements Test{
    public TestParent(){}

    private void doTest1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Override
    public void test1(){
        doTest1();
    }

    @Override
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2");
        doTest1();
    }
}
```